# Import Spring Beans in Micronaut Application with Import

Tags: micronaut

I am building a Micronaut application which uses Spring Beans. I want to import some classes which contains (Spring) bean definitions. In Spring you could do this with:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ DataSourceConfig.class, TransactionConfig.class })
public class MyConfig  {
}
```

But when I use this in my Micronaut application the beans inside DataSourceConfig and TransactionConfig are not loaded. I have setup Spring correctly, cause when I inject my own beans they appear nicely.

Any toughts on this?

Comment: The answer depends on a couple of issues.  Are you using `io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-annotation`?

Comment: Yes, but the beans are created in another library. It looks like micronaut doesn't do anything with @Import statement..

Answer (score 0):

Bean import is not implemented yet but it is a planned feature. See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1885

Comment: Thx for your reply! The issue is indeed the same issue we are running into.